# custom exception handling in mule esb

Tags: exception, mule

I have created an application where we have to throw custom exception but i am not able to do that. Just explaining the scenario:

First I have taken HTTP connector then flow goes to json to object (convert body row data to object format) and then flow goes choice message processor from there it is going to call soap web service.I have explicitly configured wsdl and all details.

If i give wrong address while configuring wsdl in web service consumer then this should throw WebServiceException which is custom exception and then this should be handled in Global Exception handler with the help of below syntax [exception.causedBy(com.custom.exceptions.WebServicesException)] but control is not going in global area.

My approach: while throwing exception i have used catch exception strategy and inside that i have custom exception strategy and inside custom exception i have thrown com.custom.exceptions.WebServicesException and this should be handled in global exception strategy withe the help of this syntax : [exception.causedBy(com.custom.exceptions.WebServicesException)] but it's not working.

i have tried every possible scenario with the help taking flow,sub flow and all but still it's not propagating to global exception handler.

could you please help me, where i am doing wrong? i didn't find any example in internet.

Thanks, Chandan

Comment: Provide SSCCE. IMHO it throws different exception. Print the exception and you will see.

Comment: @Alex: please have a look on below link for reference:  https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/57920/custom-exception-handling-in-mule-esb.html

Comment: I do have account in Mule forums but my access to this link is denied.

Comment: @Alex: please try once again.